# How to check the encryption algorithm being used in the SFTP session through WinSCP?

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am using WinSCPnet, Version=5.19.0 for file transfer using SFTP. The vendor where I was transferring file has deprecated a couple of ciphers. I want to check which cipher or encryption algorithm is being used by SFTP session which I am using in my code.

Here is my code to open the SFTP connection:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptionsSFTP = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = sftpServerIP,
    UserName = sftpUserID,
    Password = sftpPassword,
    PortNumber = sftpPort,
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = sftpHostKey,
    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
};

Session sessionSFTP = new Session();

sessionSFTP.Open(sessionOptionsSFTP);
log.Info("SFTP session has been opened");
```

Is there a way to log or check which algorithm is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check what algorithms are supported by your version of WinSCP .NET assembly, lookup the `winscp.exe` binary in your assembly package (or just [download WinSCP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/files/WinSCP/) 5.19 binary separately).

And run it with [`/info` command-line parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#info). You will get:

```
SSH encryption ciphers:
aes256-ctr
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes192-ctr
aes192-cbc
aes128-ctr
aes128-cbc
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
blowfish-ctr
blowfish-cbc
3des-ctr
3des-cbc
arcfour256
arcfour128
des-cbc
des-cbc@ssh.com
...
```

---

To check what algorithms are actually used by your session, inspect the session log file. Enable it by setting [`Session.SessionLogPath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#sessionlogpath).

```
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.501 Have a known host key of type ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.503 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519, using hash SHA-256
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.762 Server also has ssh-ed25519/ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ecdsa-sha2-nistp384/ssh-dss/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.763 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.763 ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 521 SHA256:p3ZteKYBFsSyFh18yOaczZEqoXnn135qqH1VqdIzQ8k
< 2023-10-31 12:30:38.764 Script: Authenticating...
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.765 Host key matches configured key fingerprint
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.766 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.766 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.766 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2023-10-31 12:30:38.766 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
```

---

Though I strongly discourage you from using old version of WinSCP. Use the latest version instead.